# Salesforce Communities with NPSP- Account for Community members

Tags: community, npsp

I am implementing a salesforce community for a non profit org who have NPSP package installed. We need to provide a self registration page for community members. Each member should have his own account rather than adding all members to a single account. Person accounts are not recommended for NPSP as per their documentation. So how can we create a new Household account from the registration page?

Comment: NPSP does householding automatically when a Contact is created. Is that not meeting your needs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're referring to the `CommunitySelfRegController`, you'll need to change it to do the following:

1. Create the contact first.  NPSP will automatically create the household account.
2. Retrieve the account ID of the new contact.
3. Instantiate a User record with the appropriate field values.
4. Use the `Site.createExternalUser()` method to create the user.  Don't use the old `createPortalUser()` method that is in the controller.

See [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_sites.htm) about the Site class and community user creation methods.